# Is it safe to call Application.EnableEvents or Application.DisplayAlerts in my finally block?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

We're writing a VSTO document-level customized application in C#.

For performance reasons, we repeat this pattern in many places:

```
bool displayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts;
try
{
    Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
    // some work, eg. theWorksheet.Delete();
 }
 finally
 {
     Application.DisplayAlerts = displayAlerts;
 }
```

I'm concerned that, like other VSTO wrapped functions into underlying Excel COM operations, the DisplayAlerts setter might throw an exception.

How are other people handling this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Technically, no, that is not correct.  If the code in the try {} block falls over with something really nasty then the code in the finally block can throw as well.  Obfuscating the real exception, that's always bad.  You need to wrap the finally code in a try/catch-em-all block.  That's awfully ugly, you might consider ab/using the *using* statement instead.

Comment: can you provide an example of what you mean? I had a sense that what Im doing isn't right, and the alternative, as you point out, is UGLY... how would 'using' help me?

Comment: Just a small little class that implements IDisposable.  Its constructor should have Application.DisplayAlerts = false, its Dispose() method should put it back, wrapped by try/catch.  Now you can use *using*.  I'm not going to post that, SO users tend to get a bit emotional about stuff like this :)

Comment: Turning DisplayAlerts off (=False) is a bad way hide issues in your code (there is no good way to hide issues! ;). Unfortunately there are a couple of Excel actions (such as deleting worksheets) that have no good approach. I would recommend a very small function to delete worksheets, and to add error checking manually to ensure there are no "really nasty" ways for code in try{} block to fall over. In all other cases I would recommend fixing the code so it does not display an alert in normal operation.